# Parallel Testing on iOS Devices

Tags: java, ios, selenium, instruments, appium

When attempting to test on multiple iOS device in parallel there are two issues that arise:

1. Instruments, the Mac developer tool will only run a single instance. Meaning only a single test can be ran at once.
2. iOS-Webkit-Debug-Proxy, is hard coded to run on a single port (27753) as it assumes there is only one instance of instruments

Comment: I answered my own question as i posted the question, a feature that exists for exactly this purpose. The idea is that if you have an issue you solve yourself, but feel others will have you pose the question then answer it. And if anyone else in the future asks the question the answer is available to them. Seems like a logical and helpful thing to do, no?

Comment: No, the feature I was referring to was the "would you like to answer this question" check box, which allows you write your answer and then post both question and answer together, which is what I did.

Comment: but then why raise the question at all? StackOverflow is not a tutorial site...

Comment: You are right - you can answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519 I just don't like when people asking and answering on their own questions immediately. It's my own opinion and I am writing it here since SO suggested put a comment when you are down-voting the question.

Comment: That's all fair enough, however I'm using a built in feature that was created to allow you to answer your question immediately. @AdamMartinu, the linked meta question mentions your point, and says that StackOverflow is about building a knowledge base, and that is why I raised the question.

Comment: @LiamFerris Oh, okay. I didn't see your second comment until now (sorry), and didn't know of that feature you mentioned. The "badge" mentioned in the linked article further proves you statement. When reading answers by users with many points and medals, I got the understanding that self-answering was frowned upon, and that the question should be removed instead. I now obviously see its not correct. I don't hope you read my previous post as being hateful, sorry for making such a mess :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start, from my investigations, I was only able to achieve parallel iOS testing using the git source for appium. When working from the npm install it did not work.

---

1. To run multiple instances of instruments, you must set up temp directories when creating your iOS appium node.

To do this use these arguments:

`--tmp /tmp/ios/`, `--tmp /tmp/ios6/` etc.

---

2. iOS-Webkit-Debug-Proxy can be ran on different ports by setting the REMOTE_DEBUGGER_PORT variable in the terminal.

`REMOTE_DEBUGGER_PORT=27754`

You will also need to use the --webkit-debug-proxy-port argument for the appium node.

`--webkit-debug-proxy-port 27754`

---

I wrote a script to start the hub, two android nodes, two iOS nodes and put in a few procedures to log errors.

```
pkill elenium
pkill java
pkill ios_webkit_debug_proxy
pkill node

java -jar ../libs/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role hub -port 4444 > logs/log_hub.txt 2>&1 &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    echo hub
    exit 1
fi

appium --nodeconfig /Path/to/androidOne.json -p 4823 -bp 5724 --chromedriver-port 9515 > logs/log_androidOne.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    echo node 1
    exit 1
fi
appium --nodeconfig /Path/to/androidTwo.json -p 4723 -bp 5723 --chromedriver-port 9516 > logs/log_androidTwo.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    echo node 2
    exit 1
fi

node appium --session-override --nodeconfig /Path/to/iPod.json --tmp /tmp/ios/ -p 4623 --webkit-debug-proxy-port 27753 --safari > logs/log_iPodTouch.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
echo node3
exit 1
fi

node appium --session-override --nodeconfig /Path/to/iPad.json --tmp /tmp/ios6/ -p 4523 --webkit-debug-proxy-port 27754 --safari > logs/log_iPad.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
echo node4
exit 1
fi

sleep 5
REMOTE_DEBUGGER_PORT=27753
./ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js -c UDID:27753 -d > logs/log_iwdpl.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    echo iwdpl
    exit 1
fi
REMOTE_DEBUGGER_PORT=27754
./ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js -c UDID:27754 -d > logs/log_iwdpl2.txt &
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
echo iwdpl2
exit 1
fi
```

The script starts by killing any processes that exist beforehand, be careful of killing all java processes if you are running other java things.

Hope this helps,
Liam